# Build OS X takes too much time

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, gradle, build

1. I'm using the latest version of Android Studio
2. it's not a project issue because on two other 3 others pcs (one OS X and two Windows) it compiles well
3. I'm encountering this problem with all AS projects on this Mac

When I open the project and gradle try to build debug variant after have downloaded all dependencies, the build never finish, it remains to:

```
Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app_debugCompile'
```

I tried also to speed it up using in gradle.properties

`org.gradle.parallel=true`

but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me to understand what could be happened on this Mac?

**SOLVED**

It was a dependency in an external repository that doesn't work with a long connection timeout.

Comment: You have some dependencies in a repo you cannot really connect to, and the requests timeout only after a long period / never?

Comment: @laalto i'm checking it now

Comment: @laalto it was EXACTLY as you said, i have one dependencies related to one external repositories that doesn't work with a long connection timeout, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of dependencies in an external repository Gradle cannot connect to, and the connection doesn't fail immediately but only after a very long timeout.

Either use repositories that are more reliable to connect to, or copy the dependencies locally to your project.